# Создание уникального кодированного значения

Tags: python

У меня есть список существующих значений `lockedCode = ['CODE001', 'CODE003', 'CODE005']`, мне необходимо создать новые уникальные значения, которые отсутствуют в списке  `lockedCode`. Я пытаюсь сделать через рекурсию, но результат не совсем такой какой хотелось бы.

Вот что я пытаюсь сделать:

```
def FindFreeCode(i, lockedCode):
    code = "CODE" + str(i).zfill(3)

    if code not in lockedCode:
        lockedCode.append(code)
        return i, code
    else:
        return FindFreeCode(i+1, lockedCode)


lockedCode = ['CODE001', 'CODE003', 'CODE005']

for i in range(1, 5):
    code = FindFreeCode(i, lockedCode)[1]
    i+=FindFreeCode(i, lockedCode)[0]
    print code
```

На данный момент у меня получается следующий список `[CODE002, CODE006, CODE008, CODE010]`. Т.е. они уникальные, но идут не по порядку, а через несколько элементов.
А я ожидаю что то типо такого `[CODE002, CODE004, CODE006, CODE007]`

Comment: пожалуйста. отформатируйте свой код так, чтобы была ясна вложенность.

Comment: а что мешает вам просто создать ноый список с кодами в заданном диапазоне? это будет в разы быстрее и эффективнее. и сам код будет на порядки короче.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
code = FindFreeCode(i, lockedCode)[1]
i+=FindFreeCode(i, lockedCode)[0]
```

Вы тут **два раза** вызываете функцию `FindFreeCode`, **теряя** после первого вызова возвращаемый индекс, а во второй вызов - возвращаемый код (потому что функция в прошлый свой вызов уже добавила код к списку и не будет его добавлять ещё раз, а добавит уже новый код). Вот у вас коды через один и теряются. Нужно брать сразу оба значения, которые возвращает функция и всё будет нормально:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    i, code = FindFreeCode(i, lockedCode)
    print(code)
```

Вывод:

```
CODE002
CODE004
CODE006
CODE007
```

P.S.

- Бесполезно что-то делать с переменной `i` внутри цикла, она всё-равно перезапишется на следующей итерации.
- `print code` - это формат вызова `print` во 2-й версии `Python`, а она уже не поддерживается